# Flex - Disable Soft Keyboard with checkbox

Tags: apache-flex, keyboard, air, listener

I have a TextArea and a Checkbox. I want to disable the SoftKeyboard when the checkbox is checcked, so the TextArea can be scrolled without it popping up. I can get the keyboard to disable when the Checkbox is clicked, but as soon as I click on the TextArea to scroll it pops back up. How do I enable/disable the keyboard with a checkbox? Below is my code:

```
protected function toggle_keyboard_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            checkboxStatus = event.target.selected;
            if(checkboxStatus == true){
            SoftKeyboardEvent.SOFT_KEYBOARD_DEACTIVATE;
            }else{}
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A SoftKeyboardEvent object is dispatched when a software-driven keyboard is activated or de-activated on a device or operating system. A SoftKeyboardEvent object is dispatched by a TextField or InteractiveObject that has the needsSoftKeyboardproperty set to true.